# Ways to prove a relation featuring $\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x^2\right)}{x^2}\:dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

From a previous [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4113352/evaluating-int-0-frac-pi-2x-cot-leftx-right-ln-2-left-cos-leftx) the following integral arised:
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x^2\right)}{x^2}\:dx$$
And there **user178256** linked us to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1153708/closer-form-for-int-0-infty-frac-arctanx2-log21x2x2dx) question where the user **M.N.C.E.** stated the following:

> $$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x^2\right)}{x^2}\:dx=\frac{1}{24}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln ^4\left(1+x^2\right)}{x^2}\:dx+\frac{2}{3}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan ^4\left(x\right)}{x^2}\:dx$$

My question is, how can we prove this relation without evaluating each integral while also avoiding complex numbers?

What I thought of doing is to use the following algebraic identity:
$$a^2b^2=\frac{1}{12}\left(a+b\right)^4+\frac{1}{12}\left(a-b\right)^4-\frac{1}{6}a^4-\frac{1}{6}b^4$$

This means that if we set $a=\arctan\left(x\right)$ and $b=\ln\left(1+x^2\right)$ we have:
$$\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan ^2\left(x\right)\ln ^2\left(1+x^2\right)}{x^2}\:dx=\frac{1}{12}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(\arctan \left(x\right)+\ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right)^4}{x^2}\:dx$$
$$+\frac{1}{12}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\left(\arctan \left(x\right)-\ln \left(1+x^2\right)\right)^4}{x^2}\:dx-\frac{1}{6}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan ^4\left(x\right)}{x^2}\:dx-\frac{1}{6}\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\ln ^4\left(1+x^2\right)}{x^2}\:dx$$
Though I'm having a little bit of trouble getting somewhere with the first $2$ integrals, any help will be well received.

Comment: MNCE used Cauchy's formula of analytic functions to obtain this identity. If you use $a^2b^2=\cdots$, I doubt one can obtain it.

Answer (score 2):

**A comment** regarding a possible way to go proposed by **Cornel Ioan Valean** (the author of the book, **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**)

There are two key steps in attacking the problem by real methods and avoiding contour integration.

$1)$ **The first key step**: we consider

$$I(a,b)=\int _0^{\infty }\frac{\arctan(ax)\arctan(bx)\log^2(1+x^2)}{x^2}\textrm{d}x,$$
which then we differentiate with respect to $a$ and $b$ and then use partial fraction decomposition.

$2)$ **The second (magical) key step**: prove (cleverly) and use that

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log^2(1+x^2)}{1+a^2 x^2}\textrm{d}x=\frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{\pi^3}{6}-2\log^2(2)\pi+\log^2\left(\frac{2(1+a)}{a}\right)\pi-2\pi \operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{a-1}{2a}\right)\right), \ a>0.$$

**A BIG NOTE**: The strategy described above, *with the use of the second step*, works smoothly if writing
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} x\cot(x)\log^2(\cos(x))\textrm{d}x= \frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(x)\log^2(1+x^2)}{x(1+x^2)} \textrm{d}x,$$
since all efforts are considered for calculating the trigonometric integral above. Thus, we only need the differentiation with respect to a single parameter, $\displaystyle I(a)=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\arctan(ax)\log^2(1+x^2)}{x(1+x^2)} \textrm{d}x$. The rest is represented by boring work to do of average difficulty.

**And a final note:** A solution in large steps to the trigonometric integral above, exploiting results from **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series**), is given in large steps [here](https://www.facebook.com/photo?fbid=3628797433883695&set=a.222846247812181).

**End of comment** (I hope it helps a little bit!)